# How to connect to server which is accessible from the company network?

Tags: internet, connection, ethernet

I have a IP address which I am using to connect to company server. When I am connected to company network I can access it normally. When I try to connect from my place or from some other network provider I can't do it.

I have address like 10.xx.xx.xx how can I access that server from the other networks?

Comment: That is something you should ask your network administrator about. They may set you up with a VPN, IF they want to allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a pretty large security problem if you could access a company server via IP from anywhere, on any network.. don't you think?

What you require, i think, is a VPN connection which allows you to connect to your work network (this will maintain the security aspects) which in turn would allow access to said server. I guess you have an IT department there, i'd suggest talking to them about VPN access.

See this link for more info on VPN's:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

Comment: don't agree with first sentence - you're saying the whole internet is a pretty large security problem. What happens when you enter any website address in a browser? It gets converted to ip addres and you make a connection to some company's server. Exactly as you say. The security problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: The internet IS a large security problem, is it not? That's why we program security features into everything (such as that which would handle the type of request you mention in your comment). My point, was that in HIS case, being able to access a server with business data on it without a VPN leaves it open to access from people outside the company (definitiely a security problem!).

Comment: yes the internet is a large security problem, but as I said, the problem is not because of accessing machines by ip, it's mainly because of software. If I give you my IP, I don't have any problems whatsoever since you won't be able to enter my machine.

Comment: Exactly. Think there's some crossed wires here.. your right, access via IP isn't the issue, it's the network he's using when trying to access it. Barnaby's comment covers it, the 10.xx address is private..  which is why we both gave VPN as the answer. The 'on any network' should have been emphasised more in my answer maybe...

Answer (score 3):

10.xx.xx.xx addresses are reserved as 'private'. I.e. they are specifically designed to only be accessible from the local network.
You would need to use some sort of VPN (Virtual Private Network) access gain access. Talk to your network administrator about how (and if) they want to provide access.